# kohana validation checkbox on not isset

Tags: php, html, validation, kohana

I would like to know how i can set a checkbox $_POSt at 0 when it's not checked (without adding a hidden input)

my model extends ORM :

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        'title' => array(
            array('not_empty')
        )
    );
}
```

My html form :

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="title">
<input type="checkbox" name="is_send" value="1">
</form>
```

My controller

```
try
    {
        $mymodel = ORM::factory('mymodel')->values($_POST, array("title", "is_send"));
            $mymodel->save();
    }
    catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
    {
       $errors = $e->errors();
    }
```

The problem is that when i don't check the box "is_send" i can't put is_send to 0, because it's not isset, any idea ?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
$post = $this->request->post();
$post['is_send'] = Arr::get($post, 'is_send', 0);

try
{
    $mymodel = ORM::factory('mymodel')->values($post);
    $mymodel->save();
}
catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
{
    $errors = $e->errors();
 }
```

Comment: thanks that's what i've done .. i'll mark your question as the answer :)

Comment: Thanks. The big secret to Kohana is really reading the source/API, the user docs are not great, but it provides good basic libraries to use.